# How to Generate Keyboard Input Using libevdev in C

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I would like to write an application to generate keyboard input (i.e. to the system it would look just like a button on the keyboard had been pressed) for a Linux system.  I would like to use C and xdotools are not an option.  Libevdev looks promising, but so far I haven't been able to get it to work.

First, can [libevdev](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/) do what I want?  Most of the documentation is focused on reading the incoming input and outputting it, but the API does feature a function to "Post an event through the uinput device."

There is also an example for creating a device.  I modified the example as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libevdev.h>
#include <libevdev-uinput.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int err;
    struct libevdev *dev;
    struct libevdev_uinput *uidev;

    dev = libevdev_new();
    libevdev_set_name(dev, "fake keyboard device");

    libevdev_enable_event_type(dev, EV_KEY);
    libevdev_enable_event_code(dev, EV_KEY, KEY_A, NULL);

    err = libevdev_uinput_create_from_device(dev,
        LIBEVDEV_UINPUT_OPEN_MANAGED,
        &uidev);

    if (err != 0)
        return err;

    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_A, 1);
    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_A, 0);
    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);

    libevdev_uinput_destroy(uidev);
    printf("Complete\n");
}
```

When I run this application, I don't see any errors (the error handling was removed from the above code for brevity), but I also don't see the "A" key get pressed.  Am I doing something wrong or do I have the wrong expectations for this library?

Comment: most (if not all) operating systems (and desktop environments) don't just let any program pretend to be the user keyboard. this would be a relatively simple way for your program to achieve privilege escalation

Comment: Understood.  In my environment, the program has the necessary privileges.

Comment: You could use the `/dev/input`/`/dev/input/uinput` device directly. (Just remember to try the other path, if one path does not work; the device path varies from distribution to distribution. Maybe make it configurable?) The interface is old and stable, no need to worry about compatibility issues. [Here](http://lkcl.net/software/uinput/) is an example program; it's for mouse events, but it should not be too difficult to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Interesting Nominal Animal, your example worked and then I was able to make my example work by bracketing the `libevdev_uinput_write_event` function calls with "`i = getchar()`".  I don't understand why that worked or where the fake keyboard input was going before.  Why is the call to getchar apparently needed to see the fake input on the command line?

Comment: Ah... it's just for a time delay.  Sleeping for 100 ms also works.  Thanks, I think I'll switch to just using `/dev/uinput` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code per se, it looks like a timing issue. If you're running this from within X for example, by the time the X server got the udev event, told the evdev driver to open the device, etc. the device is gone again. You should see a message to that effect in the Xorg.log.

If you check the source for libevdev, you'll see that it's really just a small wrapper around writing to /dev/uinput. All it provides is better type-safety and slightly easier code.

The delay is the easiest solution, a more complex one would be to either check that X initialized the device correctly or at least check with udev that the device appeared.