# Generate combined virtual key presses to get chars like â, ó, ć, and more complex

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qml, virtual-keyboard

I'm implementing a virtual keyboard using QML.

So far I literally map the char to print for the different key maps (w/o shift, with shift, with Alt Gr, etc.).

So I have to write down all the chars for different layouts somewhere in the code.

Especially for layouts and languages where two or more key presses generate a more complex char like pressing **`** followed by **a** to get à becomes very nasty.

So I think this is a sub-optimal approach and there is a much cleverer solution to **just provide the scan codes** (as provided by 'showkey -s' in Linux) and to use the systems locale settings to get the correct char printed in let's say a QQuick LineEdit.

What would be the best/correct way tho pass the scan codes to the system to generate "real" key events and how could I "receive" them in my code.

System is Linux. C++ backend would by fine. Guess QML alone won't be capable ...
May It be clever to generate an own keyboard input device for this ?

Or could I inject the scan codes into the existing keyboard device to simulate the presses ?

Comment: Scan codes are only applicable for hardware keyboards and physical keys. As `à` is not a physical key, it doesn't have any scan code. Qt is several layers of abstraction removed from this concept.

Comment: @n.m. I am aware of that. A simulation of the hardware would do what I need. I found that my last question leads into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code derived from

> [How to Generate Keyboard Input Using libevdev in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092855/how-to-generate-keyboard-input-using-libevdev-in-c)

using `libevdev` seems to point into the right direction.

It allows to send scan codes to a newly created keyboard device (needs root).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libevdev/libevdev.h>
#include <libevdev/libevdev-uinput.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int err;
    struct libevdev *dev;
    struct libevdev_uinput *uidev;

    dev = libevdev_new();
    libevdev_set_name(dev, "fake keyboard device");

    libevdev_enable_event_type(dev, EV_KEY);
    for(uint key = 1; key < 255; ++key) {
        libevdev_enable_event_code(dev, EV_KEY, key, nullptr);
    }

    err = libevdev_uinput_create_from_device(dev,
        LIBEVDEV_UINPUT_OPEN_MANAGED,
        &uidev);

    if (err != 0) {
        return err;
    }

    sleep(1);

    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 1);

    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_A, 1);
    //libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_A, 0);
    //libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);

    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_B, 1);
    //libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_B, 0);
    //libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);


    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_KEY, KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 0);

    libevdev_uinput_write_event(uidev, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);

    sleep(1);

    libevdev_uinput_destroy(uidev);
    printf("\nComplete\n");
}
```